# Access Query params value if passing like []

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-core-webapi, query-string

The Request URL is like below

```
?Page=1&Count=10&q[]=Name:[Abc, Xyz]&q[]=City:[XXX, YYY]&q[]=ID:[1,2]
```

I am using Asp.Net Core API and C#.

Controller code:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetUserListAsync([FromQuery]Data data)
{
   ----
   ----
}
```

Data Object class

```
public class Filters
{
    public List<string> Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> City { get; set; }
    public List<int> ID { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Filters> q { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried like this, I get the value for the fields `Page` and `Count`. But I not able to get the values for the field `q`.

How can I take the values for the field `q` from the request?

Otherwise, If I give like this as mentioned below means, how to take the values?

```
&query_hash[0][field]=Id&query_hash[0][Values][]=1&query_hash[1][field]=Date&query_hash[1][Values][from]=2020-03-11T18.30.00.000Z&query_hash[1][Values][from]=2020-03-12T18.30.00.000Z
```

Comment: but *why* is the request URL like that? that doesn't look exactly normal... and that is before escaping concerns

Comment: I can't find anywhere that states that square brackets are allowed in query parameters, without escaping.

Comment: In URL binding, it encodes like Page=1&Count=10&q%5B%5D=Name:%5BAbc,%20Xyz%5D&q%5B%5D=City:%5BXXX,%20YYY%5D&q%5B%5D=ID:%5B1,2%5D

Comment: You will need to decode that query string yourself (or at least the parts that don't decode at the moment), the `q` parameters are a non-standard format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the array in Request url like below

```
?Page=1&Count=10&q[0].Name=Abc&q[0].Name=xyz&q[0].City=AAA&q[0].ID=1&q[0].ID=2&q[1].Name=rrr
```

Result:
[image]